# How to watch the built-in editors in a VSPackage?

Tags: visual-studio-2008, add-in, vspackage

I have been reading the MSDN documentation on VSPackages about the editors and so-forth, but I am failing to see anything in the samples or on MSDN regarding watching the built-in editors from a VSPackage. It all seems to be information on building custom editors.

I would like to receive notifications when the current selected file is changed, or events happen inside the editor such as typing, and so forth.

Also, if this is not possible or a pain, I could also switch to development via a add-in?

Cheers,
MiG

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that its the Running Document Table i'm after and there is a sample in the Visual Studio SDK hooking into its various events.

There is a Deep Dive explaining it in much more detail if anyone's interested:

http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/Project/Download/FileDownload.aspx?ProjectName=RunDocEventExplrDD&DownloadId=5205